# OpenCV on Android, when do I need native code?

Tags: java, android, opencv, native

I'm looking into using OpenCV for an Android application and am running into some problems compiling the samples which use Native OpenCV.

So, my question is:

When using OpenCV, when will I need to use Native OpenCV code? Can I get by without using it (as in Tutorial 1 within the samples)?

Apologies for the vague question, I can be more specific if that would help.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do, really. Native calls are very expensive in terms of speed, so if this is relevant for your application, [you should reduce them to the minimum possible](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidBestPractices). Most of the Android OpenCV libraries rely on native calls, so going native or using OpenCV Java calls should not give a relevant increase in terms of performance time. But there is nothing like testing it.

You would also like to use native code if you already have C/C++ OpenCV implemented code. That would save you some time re-writing it in Java. You should also use native code, if the functions you want weren't already ported to Android ([it is up to 42%, currently](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV2.3.1JavaAPIcoverage)).